# Python3: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coinbase' on Mac OSX High Sierra v 10.13.3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.6, coinbase-api

**EDIT APPENDED**

Let me preface by saying: I've read through the suggested articles relating to "ModuleNotFound" error, and a number of "set path permanently mac osx" articles from searching.

My goal: use the Coinbase Python library on Mac OSX v 10.13.3

Issue: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coinbase'`

Current Configuration:

`echo $path` results in `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:`

`ls

`$ pip3 install coinbase` results in `Requirement already satisfied: coinbase in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

And finally: 
[image: Importing coinbase to Python]

Note: I can `>>>import coinbase` if I launch Python from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` like:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ python3
.......
>>> import coinbase
```

Here are the results of `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
[image]

========================================================================
EDIT 1:

`pip show coinbase` yields `Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
whereas `pip3 show coinbase` yields `Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

I used `python3 -m site` to get the following.  So now my question is: how do I configure pip3 to install to the correct location (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like the pip3 is pointed to the python3 in `/usr/local/bin` but you have another python3 perhaps in `/opt/local/bin` as that's first in your `$path`. Do you have a macports installation maybe? If so and you want to use that, then you need to `port install <package>` for it to load into that python.

Either way, I'd suggest using a virtual environment instead of the mac's default python (or macports for that matter) by using either virtualenv (easier, but python only) or anaconda (does more than python, but not quite as friendly). When you use these and activate them, it's very clear what python you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
1) no macports install
2) /usr/local/lib/python3.6/ only contains site-packages/ which are the installed libraries.
3) My python install is in /usr/local/bin/python3.6, but seems to be referencing "../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3"  I can't get the whole path to print there...
Any additional insight is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what your application with this is, but if at all possible it's best not to touch the Framework versions of python that are installed by Apple. Sometimes you have to (if you are using UI stuff for example) but if not then I'd really suggest again to use a virtualenv. It's pretty easy and then you can manage all the packages you need for each specific application/task. If you must use without virtualenv then I think you need to adjust the order of `$PATH`

Comment: I had never used virtualenv, but that is an easy solution to the problem.  There's no reason the app needs to be on my physical machine.